# Use output (returned value) of xquery function in same function

Tags: function, xslt, xquery

I am new to the xquery, and Looking for your quick help in this. Thanks a lot for looking into my issue.

I have an requirement where I need to replace multiple place holders with actual values in a given string, I have tried to implement using below XQuery function.

Problem with this function is that it is replacing all the placeholders by each time i am getting a separate string, e.g. First excution of for loop replaces first place holder and 2nd iteration replaces 2nd placeholder (but to the actual input string), I am looking for a solution where I can pass out of fist iteration to the input for 2nd Iteration.

## XQuery:

```
declare function functx:replace-place-holders-with-values (
  $MainString as xs:string? ,    
  $MappingList as node(), 
  $ActualValueList as node() )  as xs:string* 
  {
    let $MessageList:= 
      for $BalMapping at $counter
      in $MappingList//map:GetUSSDBalanceMappingRow
      let $BalanceBucket := $ActualValueList//bal:BalanceItems
        /bal:BalanceItem/bal:SubBalanceList
        /bal:SubBalanceItem
        [bal:SubBalanceType/text() = 
        $BalMapping//map:BalanceParamaterFlag/text()]
      return <MessageList>
      {
         replace($BalanceString ,
           ($BalMapping/map:BalanceParameter/text()),
            concat(
              $BalanceBucket/bal:SubBalanceValue/text(),
              '  ',
              $BalanceBucket/bal:SubBalanceUnit/text()))
      }
      </MessageList>    
      return $MessageList/text() 
  };
```

e.g.

## Input String :

```
Your Total Balance is #BAL#, Saving Bal #SAV_BAL#, FD Balance #FD_BAL#, for more details loging to example.com
```

## Output Shows:

```
Your Total Balance is 205, Saving Bal #SAV_BAL#, FD Balance #FD_BAL#, for more details loging to example.com
Your Total Balance is #BAL#, Saving Bal 105, FD Balance #FD_BAL#, for more details loging to example.com
Your Total Balance is #BAL#, Saving Bal #SAV_BAL#, FD Balance 100, for more details loging to example.com
```

## Expected Result:

```
Your Total Balance is 205, Saving Bal 105, FD Balance 100, for more details loging to example.com
```

I am happy to provider further details, please let me know if you need further details. 
Please feel free ignore above query, if you have any other solution  to achieve this using XQuery/XSLT.

Looking forward to hear back soon on this.

Comment: Welcome to SO, I changed the layout of your code to make it readable, if you post questions here, it helps to get answers quickly if to do so from the get go ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use recursion. Something like this:

```
declare function local:r($in s xs:string, $markers as xs:string*, $replacements as xs:string*) {
 if (empty($markers)) 
 then $in
 else local:r(replace($in, head($markers), head($replacements)),
         tail($markers), tail($replacements))
}
```

(head and tail are XQ30 functions, in XQ10 implement them yourself as $seq[1] and remove($seq, 1) respectively)